# Catch deleted rows on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

I use Microsoft SQL Server and my client uses PostgreSQL.

I get data from Client DB (PostgreSQL) to my database (SQL Server) with last refresh date. For example:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where date > '2012-06-13'
```

.. for today's replication and tomorrow I will run it again:

```
 select * 
 from tablename 
 where date > '2012-06-14'
```

I run this every day. But sometimes the client has deleted some rows. In this case I need to know about them on my side, too.

There is a unique `id` column. The client doesn't send me deleted `id`. I have to catch those - but how? I am loading all id column from client side to a separate table on my side one time in week, then I delete which is not exist on client db but exist on my db. And it don't work for big tables. I keep getting timeout errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you can do something on the client side, you could have a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on all of your client tables, which could put an Id and a tableName in a `DeletedEntries` table... But is that only possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to look at (obviously anything you do will require catching things on your clients' ends) is this:  http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

I have used it in a couple projects and it is great for catching historical information in tables and what happened to them.  That way you don't have to write your own triggers.